# Add the number in the column if exists

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk

I need to count `Nodes_Util` for each Queue. In the example below, `queue1` has only one line, but it varies and it could be nothing sometimes and it applies to all queues.

I want to dynamically add the number in the column if it exists.

```
Queue    | JOB_ID     | Tasks      | ptile      | Nodes_Util
queue1   | 220412     | 317        | 8          | 39
queue2   | 183623     | 317        | 16         | 19
queue2   | 220297     | 192        | 8          | 24
queue2   | 220298     | 192        | 8          | 24
queue2   | 220299     | 192        | 8          | 24
queue2   | 220300     | 192        | 8          | 24
queue2   | 220301     | 192        | 8          | 24
queue2   | 220302     | 192        | 8          | 24
queue2   | 220303     | 192        | 8          | 24
queue2   | 220304     | 192        | 8          | 24
queue2   | 220305     | 192        | 8          | 24
queue3   | 214071     | 187        | 16         | 11
queue3   | 214706     | 173        | 16         | 10
queue3   | 219981     | 128        | 16         | 8
queue3   | 220352     | 512        | 16         | 32
queue4   | 218227     | 576        | 16         | 36
queue4   | 220371     | 192        |            | 12
queue5   | 218106     | 256        | 16         | 16
queue5   | 220138     | 32         | 8          | 4
queue5   | 220382     | 16         | 8          | 2
queue5   | 220396     | 16         | 16         | 1
queue5   | 220403     | 16         | 16         | 1
queue5   | 220427     | 16         | 16         | 1
queue5   | 220566     | 32         | 8          | 4
queue6   | 219249     | 256        | 16         | 16
queue6   | 219267     | 256        | 16         | 16
queue6   | 220001     | 256        | 16         | 16
```

I need to know number of nodes utilized by each queue.

Comment: I think your question is unclear, could you provide desired example output, I assume this is input or give some more explanations.

Comment: Yes, this is this input. We want to find which queue[column: Queue] is using how many nodes [column: Nodes_Util]

Comment: from the above given input "queue2" is using 235 nodes i.e by adding all the lines which starts with "queue2"

Comment: from the above given input, i want o/p as below

queue1=39
queue2=235
queue3=61
queue4=48
queue5=29
queue6=48

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work

```
awk -F" *| *" 'NR>1{a[$1]+=$NF}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' file
```

#### Output

```
queue3 61
queue4 48
queue5 29
queue6 48
queue1 39
queue2 235
```

or if they are in order like your example

```
awk -F" *| *" 'NR==1{next}t!=$1{print t,x;x=""}{x+=$NF;t=$1}END{print t,x}' file
```

#### Output

```
queue1 39
queue2 235
queue3 61
queue4 48
queue5 29
queue6 48
```